# Nameserver setup problem - cannot add hostname

Tags: hostname, nameserver

Help on nameserver setup!!!

The issue I currently have is that I have a domain registered at GoDaddy, but I host website at different hosting company - company H. I also purchased a dedicated static IP from H. H gave me two IPs for setting up the nameserver at GoDaddy. One of the IPs is my dedicated IP address for A record.

ns1.mysite.tw- 22.33.44.55

ns2.mysite.tw- 22.33.44.56 - my dedicated IP

However, I am not able to setup the nameservers at GoDaddy with below error message. GoDaddy said that H didn’t setup the nameserver correctly, but H said that they setup correctly and GoDaddy need to add the IP to their nameservers.

===============================================================

## Error: Parameter value range error: tempname is not valid TLD

So, I don’t know which side causes this issue, but no one can help now. I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Names like `ns1` and `ns2` are usually used for DNS nameservers, not for websites. Are you certain the addresses are your dedicated web-server addresses?

I would expect you to to set up at Godaddy a name like `www.mysite.tw` with an address like `22.33.44.56`

Either you typed something other than just `www.mysite.tw` or Godaddy are not aware of the tw top level domain (TLD) - which seems unlikely if you registered `mydomain.tw` with them.

Retry using `www.mysite.tw` - if that gives the same error message, I would call/email Godadady support for assistance.

---

If the hosting company want you to get mysite.tw delegated to their nameservers, you can check the situation as follows:

```
C:\>nslookup -type=NS facebook.com

Non-authoritative answer:
facebook.com    nameserver = ns3.facebook.com
facebook.com    nameserver = ns4.facebook.com
facebook.com    nameserver = ns5.facebook.com
facebook.com    nameserver = ns1.facebook.com
facebook.com    nameserver = ns2.facebook.com

ns1.facebook.com        internet address = 204.74.66.132
ns2.facebook.com        internet address = 204.74.67.132
ns3.facebook.com        internet address = 69.63.178.21
ns4.facebook.com        internet address = 69.63.186.49
ns5.facebook.com        internet address = 69.63.176.200
```

Just substitute mysite.tw for facebook.com in the above command. It will show you that Godaddy's nameservers are managing the mysite.tw domain.

I don't use Godaddy so I don't know if you can arrange this delegation using their control panel, more likely you'd have to ask Godaddy to do this for you.

After Godaddy say they have delegated nameservice to your hosting company, run the above command again to see that the change has occurred. You will need to wait for the DNS cache period to expire.

This delegation seems unnecessary to me. I would expect you just need to discover the IP-address of the web-server hosting your site and use Godaddy's control panel to set up a DNS "A" record for www.mysite.tw pointing to that IP-address.

Comment: Yes, I setup the A record under GoDaddy by using 22.33.44.56 and I can find my website correctly. The hosting company also asked me to add ns1.mysite.tw (22.33.44.55) and ns2.mysite.tw (22.33.44.56) to GoDaddy as nameserver. this part never worked.

Comment: I don't know if the www-A record IP can be the same as NS (ns2.mysite.tw) which is 22.33.44.56 as example here. GoDaddy said they will escalated this issue to senior engineer, but I haven't heard back from them for 3 days already.

Comment: It sounds like the hosting company want Godadday to delegate mysite.tw to them. That is delegate the nameservice for the domain mysite.tw. See amended answer

Comment: Hi RedGrittyBrick, Thank you very much for your help. After a week of work with GoDaddy, they finally fix this issue. The root cause of the issue that they gave me is - my domain name was not being registered correctly. That's the reason that I cannot setup the nameserver under my GoDaddy DNS Zone.